# IOS In UIPopoverController using category for popup to Home view controller data send but its not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I have create one Home view controller and open popup on one button the popup view is one another controller this controller name is "DetailViewController" and in view controller i have create one tableview and this tableview "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method i have call one delegate method but here is delegate method is nil and not call a function 
Here is my code please give me solution

Protocall

```
MonsterSelectionDelegate.h
@protocol MonsterSelectionDelegate <NSObject>

@required

-(void)select_protocol:(NSIndexPath *)getIndexpath;
@end
```

Home View Controller.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MonsterSelectionDelegate.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<MonsterSelectionDelegate>


-(IBAction)click_pressme:(id)sender;
@end
```

Home view controller .m file

```
    -(void)select_protocol:(NSIndexPath *)getIndexpath
    {
        NSLog(@"dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf");
    }
Detailview controller .h file using for popup 

  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MonsterSelectionDelegate.h"


@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,MonsterSelectionDelegate>
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSArray *TheAry;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MonsterSelectionDelegate> delegate_view;
@end
```

Detailview controller .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate_view);
    if (self.delegate_view) {
        [self.delegate_view select_protocol:indexPath];
    }



}
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate view is null please give me solution where i do mistake please help me
```

Comment: R u pushing the viewcontroller from home to detail?

Comment: YES i am using two view controller one is main view name is Homeview and second one is Detailview in this view i am using tableview then click on tableview function run on home view controller

Comment: where u r setting the delegate to for homevc. Have you initialized the homevc in detailvc?

Comment: NO . how to initialized

Comment: In your home view controller, you need to set `delegate_view` when you present detail view controller: `detailVC.delegate_view = self;`